# How to convert android library project to fat jar

Tags: java, android, jar

I have created a library project which is dependant on another jar. When I converted my library project to jar and tried to consume this jar in my application I need to add dependant jar as well. Is there a way to convert my library project to fat jar like in java ? Fat jar must consists of dependant jar and while consuming it in application I just need to add one fat jar.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [gradle plugin](https://github.com/musketyr/gradle-fatjar-plugin) that allows for exactly that: building fat JAR files.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this [kezong fat-aar-android](https://github.com/kezong/fat-aar-android) which support **gradle plugin 3.0.0+**